# Any Microsoft SQL Server 2008 licensing restrictions on usage?

Tags: sql-server, licensing, clients

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Does Microsoft have any problems with HOW I USE SQL Server Standard Edition 2008? I plan on using it to aggregate my clients various data sources and report on them (using the whole stack - SSIS, DB, Analysis Services and Reporting Services) via the web. I don't want to run into any issues with being accused of "re-selling" services / features when I'm not allowed to, etc.

In essence, I'm charging people to build them solutions based on / using MY licensed copy and then giving them access to the final products. (reports, etc)

It seems straightforward enough - but who knows with MS...

(BTW, Licensed by processor / not CAL)

Comment: Not a programming question

Comment: This question is in no way duplicate of 215405...

Comment: @Remus:  The point is that we can't reasonably answer licensing questions specifically.  We tried to come up with a canonical answer for them.  People should not be coming to SF for hard and fast rules on their licensing questions and should, in almost EVERY circumstance, contact their vendor(s) with their specific environments and situations to be in compliance...

Answer (score 6):

As long as you are using CPU licenses, which you are you are fine.  If you have a server with two CPUs in it you'll need two CPU licenses.  You can install and use any of the SQL Server components on that server that you want, for what ever you want.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my knowledge of SQL Serve licencing (which is not complete), what you're doing sounds fine as long as you're using a per processor licence.

If you used a CAL licence it wouldn't be.

Also, something to bear in mind is the other products you use with SQL Server.
If it's just IIS that's fine, but any product like SharePoint will increase the licencing, particularily with reporting services.

You will also be limited in terms of functionality by the edition you're licensed for, typically SQL Server Standard Edition is good enough for most needs though.

Answer (score 3):

With per processor you can expose to web. with CAL you cannot, because of the [multiplexing](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/licensing.aspx) issue. As always, always consult with an MS representative for any licensing questions, don';t rely on forum answers.